# Robust way to insert string into string at varying index location

Tags: python, string

I am looking for a robust way to insert commands into GCode string lines. Given these two example lines:

```
'G1 X372.555 Y386.637 E0.07002'

'G0 F30000 X372.555 Y386.637 Z32.2'
```

I want to take the `Z32.2` from the second line, and insert it between the Y and E commands in the first line. Resulting in

```
'G1 X372.555 Y386.637 Z32.2 E0.07002'
```

At first I wanted to use the `string.find()` method similar to this:

```
line = 'G1 X372.555 Y386.637 E0.07002'
index = line.find('E')
result = line[:index] + 'Z32.2 ' + line[index:]
```

This method runs into issues because the line string does not always have an E command. If the line didn't have an E command, the desired result would be

```
'G1 X372.555 Y386.637 Z32.2'
```

The length of the string varies highly, so the index to insert the Z command would not be consistent.

Comment: To be clear, if there's no `E`, you want to insert `Z` after `Y`, right?

Comment: Will you be always having `G`, `X`, `Y` ? If yes, you can do `line.split()` to get list of words (which are space separated in your string). And use index 2 to insert `Z` in the list. And then join back the list using `list.join(' ')`. Will it work?

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri Yes, that works perfectly, thank you! At least in Python 3.10.1, the syntax seems to be `separator = '  ' `  to set the separator and then `new_line = separator.join(list) ` to join the list with the desired separator.